# Diagram animation software

Tags: video, animation, charts

I wish to create a bar chart whose bars will jump back and forth before morphing into the actual result.
Example: http://youtu.be/RqgPC1FD1sY?t=20s

**Requirements**

The ability to

- draw a diagram based on data sets (as in common spreadsheet software)
- create keyframes of the data
- output the diagram as an animation (it doesn't matter as long as the format is common)

**Bonus**

It would be perfect if the tool had a graphical user interface since I don't want to spend time on programming. However, if there are no tools available, I am open to programming library suggestions to start developing on my own.

---

**Clarification on keyframes**

The tool is supposed to let me define various states in time ("keyframes"). Later when producing the animation, the program would interpolate those states to generate frames between the keyframes.

The keyframes in this case would simply consist of different states of data tables.
Example:

```
State 1 (t = 0s):            

    |  me   | Jon Skeet
  $ |   0$  |   1000$  

State 2 (t = 2s): 

    |  me   | Jon Skeet
  $ | 500$  |    500$

State 3 (t = 3s): 

    |  me   | Jon Skeet
  $ | 1000$ |     0$
```

Comment: Have you considered a JavaScript charting library with animation? A charting library can accommodate your first and third requirements. AND the resulting charts could be made interactive. If you provide some clarification on your keyframes requirement, that would help. Any other requirements besides the ones listed here?

Comment: I added clarification on my keyframe requirement. I hoped for a tool which doesn't involve programming - if there is any. Which JS charting library would you suggest? It would be convenient if it drew on a `<canvas>`, so I can capture screenshots.